# Creating table comparing specific columns in two dataframes?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that look something like this:

```
id<-c(1,2,3,4)
age_group<-c(17-24 years,25-55 years,17-24 years,17-24 years)
gender<-c(male,male,female,female)
marital_status<-c(partnered,single,single,partnered)
education<-c(high school,university,university,university)
df1<-data.frame(id,age_group,gender,marital_status,education)

id<-c(2,3,4)
age_group<-c(25-55 years,17-24 years,17-24 years)
gender<-c(male,female,female)
marital_status<-c(single,single,partnered)
education<-c(university,university,university)
df2<-data.frame(id,age_group,gender,marital_status,education)
```

I can use the `CreateTableOne(vars = listVar, data = df1, factorVars = catVar)`code (with the content of listVar and catVar as the variables above) on each dataframe package to get the n and %:

```
                                     Overall     
  n                                           400         
  age_group (%)                                           
   17-24 years                              300 ( 75.0) 
   25-55 years                              100 ( 25.9) 
  gender (%)                                     
   Male                                     200 ( 50.0) 
   Female                                   200 ( 50.0) 
  marital_status (%)                    
   Partnered                                200 ( 50.0) 
   Single                                   200 ( 50.0) 
  education (%)                                  
   high school                              100 ( 25.0) 
   University                               300 ( 75.0)
```

But I'd like to compare my two dataframes by select characteristics to get an output like this:

```
  dataframe                                   df1               df2             p test         
  n                                           400               300
  age_group (%)                                                                 0.949
   17-24 years                              300 ( 75.0)        200 ( 66.7)
   25-55 years                              100 ( 25.9)        100 ( 33.3)
  gender (%)                                                                    0.998
   Male                                     200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)       
   Female                                   200 ( 50.0)        150 ( 50.0)
```

I did try `compare_table = compare_df(df1, df2, c("age_group","gender"))` but it didn't give me what I wanted.

Would love some suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basiclly, you can merge two dataframe to one, add a new column to mark which dataframe it originally belonged to, then you can easily use `CreateTableOne` to output what you want.

Following are codes:

```
df1$df <- c("df1")
df2$df <- c("df2")
bigdf <- rbind(df1,df2)

res <- tableone::CreateTableOne(vars = c("age_group","gender"), strata = "df",data = bigdf,factorVars = c("age_group","gender"))
print(res,showAllLevels = T)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This solved my problem! I was looking for a way to show all levels. Didn't realize there was a function! Thanks :)